# C# Paypal Sandbox's IPN simulator fails to send event because "the handshake was not verified"

Tags: c#, ssl, paypal

I am developing a Paypal IPN event listener in C#. Using Paypal's IPN simulator I was able to send events to my server and my listener would receive the event. The listener could also receive events from using the "Subscribe" button generated with Paypal's sandbox.

Starting from few days ago however, sending IPN with the simulator to my server always fails with the error message "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information." When I use openssl with the command `openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/` I get

> Loading 'screen' into random state - done CONNECTED(00000114)
>   2092:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   handshake fa ilure:.\ssl\s23_clnt.c:602:

as the result. I also noticed in the IPN history (which the events were generated by using the paypal button) of my sandbox merchant account, the HTTP status code is 500.

I've tried everything from editing the registry to enable TLS 1.2 on my server, to importing the VeriSign G5 Root Certificate with mmc. Nothing seems to be working. The certificate I'm using on my server is Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2 (SHA256RSA 2048bit).

Strange thing is, I can still receive events from the Webhook simulator. Plus, everything was working perfectly before...

Is there anyone else experiencing this? Maybe Paypal did something to the sandbox that's causing the problem?

Comment: Turns out the openssl version I used was too old and doesn't support TLS 1.2. Using version 1.0.2h the command is executed without the handshake failure. I tried to only have TLS 1.2 enabled on my server, but the IPN simulator still shows "handshake was not verified". For anyone interested, you can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html to get an idea on how secure your server is, details of your current configurations etc. Still doesn't help me with the IPN issues though... Am I the only one having this problem?